# Incompatible train and label data shape for ConvLSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am having a problem with data shape when I try to feed it into my ConvLSTM network.

I already know that the train input for ConvLSTM should be 5 dimensional (number of sequences, number of samples in each sequence, rows, columns, channels). And I know that the labels for the same network should be four dimensional as it is expected from python. So my training data set has the shape (105, 15, 30, 40, 3) and for the following label data set for training I created the array of shape (105*15, 30, 40, 3).But I am getting the following error:

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 105 input samples and 1575 target samples.

Comment: I am not sure why the labels would be four dimensional if the train is 5 dimensional. Is this part of some specific library's requirement? could you post a link to the library you are using?